# Entity Framework: how to change existing integer foreign key value in an Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

This should be a simple Entity Framework 6 question: How can I change a foreign key field value from 3 to 5 and successfully save to a Microsoft SQL Server database? My code saves other fields in the same record successfully, but does not change the foreign key field value from 3 to 5 (it remains 3 without error.)

More info:

I have a nested relation between OrderLine and Product where OrderLine is a many-to-one to Product (Product is the parent table which could be null in OrderLine.)  OrderLine has an integer foreign key field that refers to the Product productid.  Entity Framework also has the Product relation in OrderLine too in this POCO:

```
public class OrderLine {
    public int orderid     {get;set;}
    public int productid   {get;set;} // Foreign Key to Product
    public int quantity    {get;set;}
    public Product product {get;set;} // generated by Entity Framework relation
}
public class Product {
    public int productid   {get;set;}
}
```

When I change OrderLine.productid to a different value, it simply does not save the value but does modify other fields successfully like quantity.  OrderLine is `EntityState.Modified` and Product is `Unchanged` (because we're not modifying Product, just referring to a different one.)

What am I missing? Do I need to set the Entity Framework Product relation to null to get productid to save or how should the code below change to allow the save?  I would like to simply change the productid value rather than load the entire Product record from the database just to change the id value.

```
orderLine.productid = 5;
orderLine.quantity = orderLine.quantity++;
DbContext.Entry(orderLine).State = EntityState.Modified;
DbContext.SaveChanges();
// quantity increments by one and persists, productid stays 3.
```

Update:

When I add the code to set the Product relation to null `product = null` before saving, it successfully saves and refers to the other product.  I use ASP.NET MVC data binding to get an `ICollection<OrderLine> orderLines` initially in the Controller.

So strange.  `Product product` was `Unchanged` so I guess Entity Framework decides to skip the field productid because the Product data was present?  When setting Product product to null then it decides to allow the productid field to change?

Comment: You need to add configuration for foreign Keys,  I don't remember the Syntax off the top of my head but you can just use scaffolding and look at the generated code

Comment: try an annotation for FK

Comment: Is the object conained in the `orderLine` variable disconnected from the `DbContext`? If yes, how it is attached? If no, how it is retrieved? Or better show full usage example.

Comment: @IvanStoev check out the question Update area if you please.  I set product=null and it saves correctly.  Why?  MVC populated the product relation.

Comment: @johnny5 I see how to apply `ForeignKey("foreignkeyname")` on the foreign key field so that it refers to the primary key of the related table.  I assume that ForeignKey annotation changes the behavior of EF so that setting the foreign key value successfully refers to a different parent without having to set the relation field to null?  I'll have to try that out Thanks.

Comment: I just don't know why my mvc controller changes the foreign key but the api controller does not. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you point to another FK object you either need to change the Id and remove the reference to the navigation object or you have to update both the Id and the navigation object.  However, normally, if you change one and not the other, EF will throw an exception about it.  I wonder if you have that setting turned off, like did you turn off ValidateOnSaveEnabled?

Comment: I use the default, whatever that may be.  I do not specifically set `ValidateOnSaveEnabled`, but no exceptions occur either way.  If I set the relation to null and set a different foreign key id value, it persists as expected, otherwise it ignores the different id value.  I do think you are correct that there must be some Entity Framework setting controlling this behavior of foreign key values and Entity Framework relations.

Comment: @ZacharyScott I normally set the Navigation property to null whenever I change a FK reference, so that is the preferred way.  Otherwise, you'd have to hit the database to load that navigation property after you change the Id to persist it which you normally don't want to do for a lookup since you aren't really changing the data on that other table, anyway.